# Where to find Austro-Hungarian WW1 medals information?

Tags: world-war-1

I'm trying to help a friend whose grandfather *was drafted into the Austro-Hungary army during WWI and won a bunch of medals including the iron cross.*

Where do I find records on medals awarded to combatants who served in Austro-Hungarian army during WWI?

Comment: The Iron Cross is not an Austrian medal, but a Prussian/German one.

Comment: yes lejonet - it may have been a family memory like "grandpa won a medal like the iron cross" and so I have asked the friend if his family kept any medals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will first need to know where the grandfather lived to find out where to look. There is the "[Kriegsarchiv](https://www.statearchives.gv.at/kriegsarchiv)" (War Archive) of the Austrian State Archives which claims to hold

> "Belohnungsakten" (reward files), which included badges of courage etc. ("old" and "new" files)

It also says that

> [t]he Kriegsarchiv does not keep all documents on military personnel before 1918. As from 1868, records were decentralised so that the documents remained in the provinces and successor states when the dual monarchy broke down

That means that depending on where in the monarchy the grandfather lived something might be in Vienna, but could also be in Budapest, Praha, Trnava, Warszawa etc.

Comment: thanks - that was very useful and helped me to get started. The birth place I was given was Jasine, the Anglicised version of Yasinia in the Ukraine. I found that the Hungarian name was Körösmező and on a map of Austro-Hungary I found that to have been on the Hungary side of the Carpathian mountains. Thus the Austrian state archives website points me to the Hungarian Military museum in Budapest.  Their website is in Hungarian and so I have asked a Hungarian friend to help out.

Comment: I've had good results with Google Translate, both for translating websites and even correspondence with archives.